# Deserialize xml.data in python

Tags: python, xml, deserialization, elementtree

I have a xml file with a lot of properties. All the attrib have the same name <prop name =....
But i only want to know some of the attrib. How can i choose the ones i want?

I did have a solution but it required adding id's to the attrib so that i could choose which one i wanted. But this required tweeking in the xml file. And as for mine research thesis I can't change the xml  file. So is  there a command or a piece of code i can use to let python know, that i want only want the propertie name which value it's Geometry? for example.

If i call properties i keep getting all of them. And i don't know how i can filter this part to get the ones i want. Any advice?

I added mine solution in python. But there must be a way without tweeking in the xml right.
[Xml data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaWoP.png)
[Python code calling prop name Geometry by adding ids in the xmlfile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YgWV.png)

```
'''
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET


#parse 
mytree = ET.parse('C:/Users/f.badloe/.spyder-py3\Stagefiles/ASD_18_244_KW_0001_WM0230(BaseanlogROB).xml') # data van xml naar python
myroot = mytree.getroot() # data zoeken in de xml file

#print (myroot.tag)
#print (myroot[2][0][0][0].tag)

#myroot[2].set('Test','20')


'''
for reference in myroot.iter('prop'):
   print(reference.attrib)
   print(reference.text)
'''


'''all shapes of the figures 
'''



for shape in myroot.iter('shape'):
    
    shapeType = shape.attrib['shapeType']
    shapeName =shape.attrib['Name']
    print(shapeName)





'''

id=1
for z in myroot.iter('prop'):
    z.set('id', str(id))
    id += 1
    #print(z.attrib)
'''

''' Geometries values of all shapes individual manier 1 '''

'''
Geometry = myroot.find(".//prop[@id='35']")
print(Geometry.text)
print(Geometry.attrib)  
 
Geometry = myroot.find(".//prop[@id='65']")
print(Geometry.text)
print(Geometry.attrib) 
 
Geometry = myroot.find(".//prop[@id='95']")
print(Geometry.text)
print(Geometry.attrib)
   
Geometry = myroot.find(".//prop[@id='124']")
print(Geometry.text)
print(Geometry.attrib)  

Geometry = myroot.find(".//prop[@id='147']")
print(Geometry.text)
print(Geometry.attrib)  

Geometry = myroot.find(".//prop[@id='170']")
print(Geometry.text)
print(Geometry.attrib)  

Geometry = myroot.find(".//prop[@id='192']")
print(Geometry.text)
print(Geometry.attrib)  
'''

'''manier 2 '''

#for elements in myroot.findall(".//shape//prop[@name = 'Geometry']"):
    
    #print(elements.text, shapeName)
     
for elements in myroot.findall(".//shape//prop[@name = 'Location']"):
    
    print(elements.text)





#nieuwe xml file
mytree.write ('ASD_18_244_KW_0001_WM0230')
'''
'''
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<panel version="14">
 <properties>
  <prop name="Name">
   <prop name="nl_NL.utf8"></prop>
  </prop>
  <prop name="Size">125 112</prop>
  <prop name="BackColor">BNO_DonkerGrijs</prop>
  <prop name="RefPoint">38 53</prop>
  <prop name="InitAndTermRef">True</prop>
  <prop name="SendClick">False</prop>
  <prop name="RefFileName"></prop>
  <prop name="DPI">96</prop>
  <prop name="PDPI">141.951</prop>
  <prop name="ConnectorPoints">
   <prop name="Location" id="1">28 63</prop>
   <prop name="Location" id="2">53 38</prop>
   <prop name="Location" id="3">28 13</prop>
   <prop name="Location" id="4">3 38</prop>
  </prop>
  <prop name="layoutType">None</prop>
 </properties>
 <events>
  <script name="ScopeLib" isEscaped="1"><![CDATA[public void SetVisibility(bool visible)
{
  Waarde.visible(visible);
  Uom.visible(visible);
  Naam.visible(visible);
  High.visible(visible);
  Low.visible(visible);
  Cirkel.visible(visible);
  KLIKFRAME.visible(visible);
}

string dp,
       naam,
       uom,
       dpQdwState,
       dpMeting;

DatapuntDescription dpDesc;

void Init()
{
  int dpConnectRetVal;

  dp = $dp;
  naam = $naam;
  uom = $uom;
  dpQdwState = dp + &quot;.QdwState&quot;;
  dpMeting = dp +&quot;.QfVal&quot;;

  dpDesc.setDp(dp);
  KLIKFRAME.toolTipText(dpDesc.sDescription);

  //datapunt connectie
  dpConnectRetVal = dpConnect( &quot;Callback&quot;, true, dpQdwState,
                                                 dpMeting);
  CheckDpConnect(dpConnectRetVal, getLastError());

  Naam.text = naam;
  Uom.text = uom;
  Waarde.format = $format;
}

void Callback(string DPE1, bit32 states,
              string DPE2, float meting)
{
  Waarde.text = meting;
  Waarde.format = $format;

  bool warning = getBit(states, 6),
       alarm   = getBit(states, 7),
       low     = getBit(states, 10),
       high    = getBit(states, 11);

  string color;

  if(warning)
  {
    color = &quot;BNO_Geel&quot;;
  }
  else if(alarm)
  {
    color = &quot;BNO_Rood&quot;;
  }
  else
  {
    color = &quot;BNO_Wit&quot;;
  }

  Cirkel.foreCol(color);

  if(low)
  {
    Low.backCol(color);
  }
  else
  {
    Low.backCol(&quot;_Transparent&quot;);
  }

  if(high)
  {
    High.backCol(color);
  }
  else
  {
    High.backCol(&quot;_Transparent&quot;);
  }
}

void OpenOnderhoud()
{
  OpenFaceplate(dp , dpDesc.sDescription);
}
]]></script>
  <script name="Initialize" isEscaped="1"><![CDATA[main()
{
  Init();
}
]]></script>
 </events>
 <shapes>
  <shape Name="Waarde" shapeType="PRIMITIVE_TEXT" layerId="0">
   <properties>
    <prop name="serialId">1</prop>
    <prop name="Type"></prop>
    <prop name="RefPoint">41 28</prop>
    <prop name="Enable">True</prop>
    <prop name="Visible">True</prop>
    <prop name="ForeColor">BNO_Wit</prop>
    <prop name="BackColor">_Window</prop>
    <prop name="TabOrder">0</prop>
    <prop name="ToolTipText">
     <prop name="nl_NL.utf8"></prop>
    </prop>
    <prop name="TransparentForMouse">True</prop>
    <prop name="layoutAlignment">AlignNone</prop>
    <prop name="snapMode">Point</prop>
    <prop name="DashBackColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="AntiAliased">False</prop>
    <prop name="LineType">[solid,oneColor,JoinBevel,CapProjecting,1]</prop>
    <prop name="BorderZoomable">False</prop>
    <prop name="FillType">[outline]</prop>
    <prop name="Geometry">1 0 0 0.7857142857142857 -13 9</prop>
    <prop name="Location">41 28</prop>
    <prop name="Font">
     <prop name="nl_NL.utf8">Arial Narrow,-1,11,5,50,0,0,0,0,0,Standaard</prop>r
    </prop>
    <prop name="Text">
     <prop name="nl_NL.utf8">Waarde</prop>
    </prop>
    <prop name="Distance">2</prop>
    <prop name="BorderOffset">2</prop>
    <prop name="Bordered">False</prop>
    <prop name="Fit">True</prop>
    <prop name="Transformable">False</prop>
    <prop name="TextFormat">[0.3f,False,False,AlignHCenter,False,False]</prop>
   </properties>
  </shape>
  <shape Name="Uom" shapeType="PRIMITIVE_TEXT" layerId="0">
   <properties>
    <prop name="serialId">2</prop>
    <prop name="Type"></prop>
    <prop name="RefPoint">75 28</prop>
    <prop name="Enable">True</prop>
    <prop name="Visible">True</prop>
    <prop name="ForeColor">BNO_Wit</prop>
    <prop name="BackColor">_Window</prop>
    <prop name="TabOrder">1</prop>
    <prop name="ToolTipText">
     <prop name="nl_NL.utf8"></prop>
    </prop>
    <prop name="TransparentForMouse">True</prop>
    <prop name="layoutAlignment">AlignNone</prop>
    <prop name="snapMode">Point</prop>
    <prop name="DashBackColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="AntiAliased">False</prop>
    <prop name="LineType">[solid,oneColor,JoinBevel,CapProjecting,1]</prop>
    <prop name="BorderZoomable">False</prop>
    <prop name="FillType">[outline]</prop>
    <prop name="Geometry">1.409090909090909 0 0 0.8571428571428571 -77.68181818181817 20</prop>
    <prop name="Location">75 28</prop>
    <prop name="Font">
     <prop name="nl_NL.utf8">Arial Narrow,-1,11,5,50,0,0,0,0,0,Standaard</prop>
    </prop>
    <prop name="Text">
     <prop name="nl_NL.utf8">Uom</prop>
    </prop>
    <prop name="Distance">2</prop>
    <prop name="BorderOffset">2</prop>
    <prop name="Bordered">False</prop>
    <prop name="Fit">True</prop>
    <prop name="Transformable">False</prop>
    <prop name="TextFormat">[0s,,,AlignHCenter]</prop>
   </properties>
  </shape>
  <shape Name="Naam" shapeType="PRIMITIVE_TEXT" layerId="0">
   <properties>
    <prop name="serialId">3</prop>
    <prop name="Type"></prop>
    <prop name="RefPoint">67 37</prop>
    <prop name="Enable">True</prop>
    <prop name="Visible">True</prop>
    <prop name="ForeColor">BNO_Wit</prop>
    <prop name="BackColor">_Window</prop>
    <prop name="TabOrder">2</prop>
    <prop name="ToolTipText">
     <prop name="nl_NL.utf8"></prop>
    </prop>
    <prop name="TransparentForMouse">True</prop>
    <prop name="layoutAlignment">AlignNone</prop>
    <prop name="snapMode">Point</prop>
    <prop name="DashBackColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="AntiAliased">False</prop>
    <prop name="LineType">[solid,oneColor,JoinBevel,CapProjecting,1]</prop>
    <prop name="BorderZoomable">False</prop>
    <prop name="FillType">[outline]</prop>
    <prop name="Geometry">1.758538587848933 0 0 1 -90.44162561576357 24</prop>
    <prop name="Location">67 37</prop>
    <prop name="Font">
     <prop name="nl_NL.utf8">Arial Narrow,-1,11,5,50,0,0,0,0,0,Standaard</prop>
    </prop>
    <prop name="Text">
     <prop name="nl_NL.utf8">NAAM</prop>
    </prop>
    <prop name="Distance">2</prop>
    <prop name="BorderOffset">2</prop>
    <prop name="Bordered">False</prop>
    <prop name="Fit">True</prop>
    <prop name="Transformable">False</prop>
    <prop name="TextFormat">[0s,,,AlignHCenter]</prop>
   </properties>
  </shape>
  <shape Name="High" shapeType="POLYGON" layerId="0">
   <properties>
    <prop name="serialId">4</prop>
    <prop name="Type"></prop>
    <prop name="RefPoint">90 40</prop>
    <prop name="Enable">True</prop>
    <prop name="Visible">True</prop>
    <prop name="ForeColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="BackColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="TabOrder">3</prop>
    <prop name="ToolTipText">
     <prop name="nl_NL.utf8"></prop>
    </prop>
    <prop name="layoutAlignment">AlignNone</prop>
    <prop name="snapMode">Point</prop>
    <prop name="DashBackColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="AntiAliased">True</prop>
    <prop name="LineType">[solid,oneColor,JoinBevel,CapProjecting,1]</prop>
    <prop name="BorderZoomable">False</prop>
    <prop name="FillType">[solid]</prop>
    <prop name="Geometry">1 0 0 1 -70.00000000000003 -14</prop>
    <prop name="Closed">True</prop>
    <prop name="Points">
     <prop name="Location">90 40</prop>
     <prop name="Location">98 30</prop>
     <prop name="Location">106 40</prop>
    </prop>
   </properties>
  </shape>
  <shape Name="Low" shapeType="POLYGON" layerId="0">
   <properties>
    <prop name="serialId">6</prop>
    <prop name="Type"></prop>
    <prop name="RefPoint">90 50</prop>
    <prop name="Enable">True</prop>
    <prop name="Visible">True</prop>
    <prop name="ForeColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="BackColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="TabOrder">5</prop>
    <prop name="ToolTipText">
     <prop name="nl_NL.utf8"></prop>
    </prop>
    <prop name="layoutAlignment">AlignNone</prop>
    <prop name="snapMode">Point</prop>
    <prop name="DashBackColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="AntiAliased">True</prop>
    <prop name="LineType">[solid,oneColor,JoinBevel,CapProjecting,1]</prop>
    <prop name="BorderZoomable">False</prop>
    <prop name="FillType">[solid]</prop>
    <prop name="Geometry">1.142857142857143 0 0 1 -82.85714285714288 -34</prop>
    <prop name="Closed">True</prop>
    <prop name="Points">
     <prop name="Location">90 50</prop>
     <prop name="Location">97 60</prop>
     <prop name="Location">104 50</prop>
    </prop>
   </properties>
  </shape>
  <shape Name="Cirkel" shapeType="ELLIPSE" layerId="0">
   <properties>
    <prop name="serialId">8</prop>
    <prop name="Type"></prop>
    <prop name="RefPoint">30.5 48.5</prop>
    <prop name="Enable">True</prop>
    <prop name="Visible">True</prop>
    <prop name="ForeColor">BNO_Wit</prop>
    <prop name="BackColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="TabOrder">6</prop>
    <prop name="ToolTipText">
     <prop name="nl_NL.utf8"></prop>
    </prop>
    <prop name="layoutAlignment">AlignNone</prop>
    <prop name="snapMode">Point</prop>
    <prop name="DashBackColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="AntiAliased">True</prop>
    <prop name="LineType">[solid,oneColor,JoinBevel,CapProjecting,2]</prop>
    <prop name="BorderZoomable">False</prop>
    <prop name="FillType">[solid]</prop>
    <prop name="Geometry">0.8508771929824561 0 0 0.8508771929824561 2.048245614035088 -3.267543859649122</prop>
    <prop name="Center">30.5 48.5</prop>
    <prop name="X-Radius">28.5</prop>
    <prop name="Y-Radius">28.5</prop>
   </properties>
  </shape>
  <shape Name="KLIKFRAME" shapeType="RECTANGLE" layerId="0">
   <properties>
    <prop name="serialId">10</prop>
    <prop name="Type"></prop>
    <prop name="RefPoint">385 122</prop>
    <prop name="Enable">True</prop>
    <prop name="Visible">True</prop>
    <prop name="ForeColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="BackColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="HoverForeCol">BNO_Wit</prop>
    <prop name="TabOrder">7</prop>
    <prop name="ToolTipText">
     <prop name="nl_NL.utf8"></prop>
    </prop>
    <prop name="layoutAlignment">AlignNone</prop>
    <prop name="snapMode">Point</prop>
    <prop name="DashBackColor">_Transparent</prop>
    <prop name="AntiAliased">False</prop>
    <prop name="LineType">[solid,oneColor,JoinBevel,CapProjecting,1]</prop>
    <prop name="BorderZoomable">False</prop>
    <prop name="FillType">[solid]</prop>
    <prop name="Geometry">0.1256281407035175 0 0 0.5039370078740157 4.633165829145731 13.51968503937009</prop>
    <prop name="BorderStyle">Normal</prop>
    <prop name="Location">385 122</prop>
    <prop name="Size">-399 -128</prop>
    <prop name="CornerRadius">0</prop>
    <prop name="Transformable">True</prop>
   </properties>
   <events>
    <script name="Clicked" isEscaped="1"><![CDATA[main(mapping event)
{
  OpenOnderhoud();
}
]]></script>
   </events>
  </shape>
  <reference parentSerial="-1" Name="IOERROR" referenceId="1">
   <properties>
    <prop name="FileName">Generiek/Symbolen/SymIOFAIL.pnl</prop>
    <prop name="Location">0 0</prop>
    <prop name="Geometry">5.555555555555555 0 0 7.11111111111111 2.999999999999999 11</prop>
    <prop name="TabOrder">8</prop>
    <prop name="dollarParameters">
     <prop name="dollarParameter">
      <prop name="Dollar">$dp</prop>
      <prop name="Value">$dp</prop>
     </prop>
    </prop>
    <prop name="layoutAlignment">AlignNone</prop>
   </properties>
  </reference>
 </shapes>
 <groups>
  <layout parentSerial="-1" Name="LAYOUT_GROUP1" serial="0">
   <properties>
    <prop name="shapeSerial">2</prop>
    <prop name="shapeSerial">1</prop>
    <prop name="isContainerShape">False</prop>
    <prop name="layoutType">Grid</prop>
   </properties>
  </layout>
 </groups>
</panel>

'''
```

Comment: Please post XML markup and Python code as text, not as images.

Comment: Sorry now i did

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution without tweeking in the xml file.
With this command i could pick which property i needed.

```py
for prop in myroot.findall(".//shape[@Name= 'Waarde']//prop[@name ='RefPoint']"):
   print(prop.text)
```